# Mongoose Complex Query by Subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find a Project by either `Owner`, `Manager`, or one of the `Team` `Member`s. Here's how the schema looks like:

```
var project = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, require: true },
  slug: { type: String, require: true },
  description: { type: String, require: true },
  descriptionHtml: { type: String, require: true },
  nextVanityId: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  owner: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Member', require: true },
  teams: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }],
  managers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Member' }]
};

var team = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  slug: { type: String, require: true },
  project:  { type: ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'Project' },
  created: { type: Date, require: true, default: Date.now },
  members: [{ type: ObjectId, default: null, ref: 'Member' }]
};
```

My query method looks like this:

```
function findByMember (member, done) {
  var id = member._id;

  Project
    .find()
    .or([
      { owner: id },
      { managers: id },
      { 'teams.members': id }
    ])
    .exec(done);
}
```

Currently it works for both owners and managers, but I'm drawing blanks when querying the members collection of each team. What should I use?

Comment: You're searching for `Product.teams.members` which doesn't exist. Do you mean you want to search for (sudo) `or: ["Project.owner", "Project.managers", "Team.members"]`?

Comment: Nico your `teams` properties is just a reference to another document. When doing the query mongo has no ideia that `teams` has a `members` property. To do the query has is you need to create the `teams` as an embedded document.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first sentence... In your current setup, you'd need to query `Team` by `members: id`, and then query `Project` by `or: [{owner: id}, {managers: id}, {teams: teamQueryResponse._id}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your query to work you can approach the problem in 2 ways.

### Solution 1

Have your teams as an embedded document in projects:

```
var team = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  slug: { type: String, require: true },
  project:  { type: ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'Project' },
  created: { type: Date, require: true, default: Date.now },
  members: [{ type: ObjectId, default: null, ref: 'Member' }]
};

var project = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, require: true },
  slug: { type: String, require: true },
  description: { type: String, require: true },
  descriptionHtml: { type: String, require: true },
  nextVanityId: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  owner: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Member', require: true },
  teams: [team],
  managers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Member' }]
};
```

This way your project document will have the team information and the `teams.members` makes sense.

### Solution 2

Denormalise your `Team` data to have only the relevant information embedded:

```
var team = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  slug: { type: String, require: true },
  project:  { type: ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'Project' },
  created: { type: Date, require: true, default: Date.now },
  members: [{ type: ObjectId, default: null, ref: 'Member' }]
};

var project = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, require: true },
  slug: { type: String, require: true },
  description: { type: String, require: true },
  descriptionHtml: { type: String, require: true },
  nextVanityId: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  owner: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Member', require: true },
  teams: [{
    _id: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Team' },
    members: [{ type: ObjectId, default: null, ref: 'Member' }]
  }],
  managers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Member' }]
};
```

In this second approach you need to keep the `Team` document and the denormalised data in sync.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did **(Solution 1)**. I was about to post it as an answer but you beat me to it :)